# Multiple field filters in a Tabular DAX Row Filter

Tags: dax

I recently implemented a Dynamic Row Filter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231092.aspx) on a Tabular Model.

For the purposes of this question, let's assume it's a simple **=[Country]="US"** DAX filter. This works just fine.

I would like to add a second filter *on the same table* to further restrict results by state. The obvious solution that comes to mind is something like this: **=[Country]="US" && [State]="CA"** but this does not work.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: Did you try putting parentheses around it? =(([Country] = "US") && ([State] = "yes"))

Comment: @mmarie Thank you for your response. I am pretty sure I did. Does it work for you?

Comment: I have something somewhat similar tested and in production: =('Job'[Job Code] ="XXXX1" || 'Job'[Job Code] ="XXXX2" ||'Job'[Job Code] ="XXXX3")

Comment: @@mmarie The key difference is you are applying multiple filters on the same field "Job". That works for me too. I am trying to apply conditions on two different fields at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but it came up for me when I searched for the same thing but ended up figuring out on my own, so I'll leave my findings for anyone else having the same problem.

To solve your particular problem you need to put the filter like this:

```
=AND([Country]="US",[State]="CA")
```

It's as simple as that, the only proboem is that if you have more than 2 filters you need to put them like this:

```
=AND(filter1,AND(filter2,AND(filter3,filter4)))
```

Because on DAX you can't use a single **AND** like in excel.